Multi-Character character constant error in C - but only one character in the variable
I'm working my way through an online C tutorial, and I've been given an example to do.  The example code creates a variable as follows:
char currency = '$';

I've entered my code as below:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int items = 50;
    float cost_per_item = 9.99;
    float total_cost = items * cost_per_item;
    char currency = '$';

    // Output
    printf("Number of items: %d\n", items);
    printf("Cost per item: %c%.2f\n", currency, cost_per_item);
    printf("Total cost = %c%.2f\n", currency, total_cost);
}

This code compiles, and runs.  But if I change the declaration of currency as follows:
char currency = '£';

it doesn't work, and I get the following error:
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] char currency = 'Â£';

The output from the code is as follows:
Number of items: 50
Cost per item: ú9.99
Total cost = ú499.50

Any idea what is wrong here?  How can I use the '£' symbol in my code?

The problem is that you've got the UTF-8 encoding for £ (which needs 2 bytes), yet the variable you're assigning to is a single character.  One easy fix is to use char currency[] = "£"; as the declaration and replace the %c conversion specifications with %s:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int items = 50;
    float cost_per_item = 9.99;
    float total_cost = items * cost_per_item;
    char currency[] = "£";

    // Output
    printf("Number of items: %d\n", items);
    printf("Cost per item: %s%.2f\n", currency, cost_per_item);
    printf("Total cost = %s%.2f\n", currency, total_cost);
    return 0;
}

When run on a MacBook Pro (M3) running macOS Sonoma 14.7.1 (and LANG=en_US.UTF-8 set in the environment, but none of the LC_* environment variables), it produces:
Number of items: 50
Cost per item: £9.99
Total cost = £499.50


Well thank you for that - I will give it a try! Honestly have to say that I don’t think much of the tutorial I’m using if they didn’t explain this in the first place!

@Student228: Handling UTF-8 characters is a rather advanced topic. Therefore, it is good for a tutorial to first show you how to deal with plain ASCII characters. For this reason, I would not blame the tutorial you are using, unless that tutorial itself was using non-ASCII characters such as £.

Supposedly C23 should have char8_t and u8 string prefixes. However gcc doesn't seem to implement that (yet) for whatever the reason. I rarely ever use UTF-8 myself, so I have no idea of the story behind all of that.

@AndreasWenzel - a fair point. The tutorial used ‘$’ for currency (probably because it was produced by a programmer from the USA) but as I am in the UK I wanted to see if I could use the ‘£’ symbol. I don’t think the tutorial specifically mentioned that char only supports standard ASCII characters, I will have to go back and check.

@Student228: It's not as simple as "char only supports standard ASCII characters".  You need to know which character set your terminal uses (and all your customers' terminals use) to be able to configure things properly.  G11N (globalization), L10N (localization) and I18N (internationalization) are interrelated topics and tricky — and not handled by most first courses in C.  (The numbers in the acronyms are the number or elided characters.)  Introductory books rarely teach about multibyte code sets (like UTF-8) or wide-character code sets, or the complexities of code sets with shift states.

To work with a UTF8 you can either work with an array of char:
char currency[] = "£";
// In this case, the array will have wide characters:
// currency[0] = 0xc2;
// currency[1] = 0xa3;
// currency[2] = 0;

Or you need to work with a wide char:
wchar_t currency = L'£';

Working with a string is easy, just do printf("%s", currency); It should print that single symbol (if your console accepts it).
But if you decide to work with wide char, you would need to use long flag: "%lc"
It is also a good idea to read locale from environment:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    int items = 50;
    float cost_per_item = 9.99;
    float total_cost = items * cost_per_item;
    wchar_t currency = L'£';

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    // Output
    printf("Number of items: %d\n", items);
    printf("Cost per item: %lc%.2f\n", currency, cost_per_item);
    printf("Total cost = %lc%.2f\n", currency, total_cost);
}


In your answer, you wrote: "To work with UTF8 you can either work with [...] Or you need to work with a wide char" -- This does not make sense to me, because a UTF-8 character is something else than a wide character. You may want to improve the structure of this sentence. Did you maybe mean: "You can either work with a UTF-8 string [...]"?

@AndreasWenzel How about now?

The structure of your sentences still does not make sense to me. You are writing "To work with UTF-8 [...] you need to work with with a wide char", which does not make sense to me. These two parts belong together due to your use of the word "either". However, if you remove the word "either", it would make sense. Or you could move the position of the word "either", so that it refers to either using UTF-8 or a wide char. For example, you could write as the first sentence the following: "You can either work with UTF-8 by working with an array of char:"
